# (Flutter / Riverpod) Cannot use ref functions after the dependency of a provider changed but before the provider rebuilt

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm encountering the error message `'Cannot use ref functions after the dependency of a provider changed but before the provider rebuilt'` while using Riverpod in my Flutter application. I read the discussion on https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/815, but I'm still unable to determine the cause of this error in my app. I've tried to create a minimal code example to reproduce the error, but I'm having difficulty doing so. I'm requesting help to provide me with a minimal code example that causes this error, with or without Flutter, on DartPad. Thank you!

Versions I am using:

- Flutter: 3.3.9
- riverpod: 2.1.1

Comment: I suppose that you rre using ref.read().someMethod() inside Widget.build() method which is not allowed

Comment: @Kirill Thank you for your comment. Yes. But I put it inside of "WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback". Is this still not allowed?

Comment: Even if that fixes it, it is smelling of trying to change the model that your view is presenting while the view is being computed.  That's a definite logic error.  You should get all your ducks in a row before you even start the first line of build().

Comment: Yeah, addPostFrameCallback make it work. But its antipattern. Your methods should be attached to collbacks (Buttons, TextFields, Dropdowns etc). If you still want to use 'addPostFrameCallback' way, try hooks_riverpod package. But it's transition for react developers. You have exclent state management with riverpod itself

Comment: @Kirill, Randal Schwartz Thank you. I am now developing a song playback app. When a user taps on a ListTile of a particular song from the list of songs, the app should transition to the playback screen, and the selected song should start playing. Currently,  the method "ref.read().someMethod()" exists inside the "addPostFrameCallback" of the playback screen. But, you mean this method should exist inside the onTap callback function of the ListTile in the list of songs, right?

Comment: @Kirill, Randal Schwartz To be honest, I want the song to start playing only after the playback screen is fully built. Where to put this method to play a song to fulfill my idea?

Comment: Yes, you can put your method inside of ListTile.onTap(). Or you can call this method right after provider initialization. e.g.: final someProvider=Provider(...); someProvider.someMethod(); return someProvider;

Then you need to 'touch' your provider to start intialization. Calling ref.read() during build method (Without any methods or assignment) should be enough

Comment: @Kirill Thank you for your answer, but I cannot understand what I should do. I will repost another question.